# GameScene size is wider than my device screen size

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working with swift and SpriteKit and I'm having an issue with what I believe is my GameScene being wider than my device's screen size. What I need to do is move an image and then not allow it to move past the edges of the screen.

Where I'm at right now is that my image will collide with the top and bottom of the screen, but it will move off to the left or right and collide with the edge somewhere off screen.

I came across this question in my searches to try and fix the problem:
[Screen's real size is bigger than what I see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042580/screens-real-size-is-bigger-than-what-i-see)

Just doing what they tried and commenting out the line that says `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill` will cause collisions with the edge of the screen to work properly, however like they stated, the image is now not scaled properly and in my case only takes up the middle leaving grey edges to each side.

Their other remedy was adding `scene = GameScene(size: self.view.frame.size)` after taking out the default created scene in, I'm assuming, `GameViewController.swift` but I wasn't sure what to remove to try doing that.

My `viewDidLoad` currently looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {

            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            //skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)

        }

    }
```

If someone could help by pointing me in the right direction for what to remove or what else to try that might fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a scene you can give the size you want, such as w: 2, h: 3. Oh sometimes w: 100 h: 50, this can be confusing for the resolutions of the device and create the point of origin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead of viewDidLoad and initialize your scene with `skView.bounds.size`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.showsPhysics = true
        skView.showsDrawCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */

        if(skView.scene == nil){

            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.size  = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }


    }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` the final size of view may not be know yet and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is sometimes better place to initialize the scene.

When scene is loaded from .sks file it has default size of 1024x768. That's why your scene is sometimes wider than expected, and this can be changed like from the code I've posted.

If you have trouble with wrong view's size (but I doubt that) check your launch images...If those are wrongly selected, a view can have a wrong size.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var scene = GameScene(size: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

or:

```
var dev_w = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width*2
var dev_h = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height*2
var new_frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, dev_w, dev_h)
var scene = GameScene(size: new_frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with Objective-C iOS 7 and 8 in SpriteKit. When replacing a `SKScene` with another, setting the next `SKScene` size with `self.size` would cause this exact error. My solution was as simple as:

```
//ObjectiveC
MyScene *newScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height * 2)];
newScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

//Swift
var newScene : MyScene = MyScene(size:CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
newScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```